# InfoPath metadata for columns that are not user input; making an acknowledgment form

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath, permissions

I am currently building a workflow that allows an admin to upload a pdf, assign it to users, and email a link to assignees requiring them to tick a checkbox saying they read the pdf.

Most of the data I need to store from the users is known by SP already, such as log in name and current time.  I need to store these values and I don't want the assigned user to be permitted to change these.

1)
Is there a custom workflow action that could immediately follow assigning the task, that will open the form in the browser when the user clicks a link (in an email).

2)
Can I save user data such as log in name and current time in a column in the form library?

3)
If I give an assignee contribute permissions on the form library in order to complete the form and task, will they be able to edit other user's form information as well?

Thank you all so much for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can create an email link that will open the form in the browser
   provided you have InfoPath services available.
2. Yes, you can retrieve the data from the list, and save it to an
   additional column.  You do this inside InfoPath or with workflow
   variables.
3. Yes, its possible.  If you want to restrict this you have to use
   item level security, or develop a method to roll back changes, such
   as having a workflow validate the Modified by is equal to the
   created by You can get creative and say copy an item from a less restrictive list to a more restrictive list as well.  Beyond that you may have to open Visual Studio and look implementing some event receivers.